# Bluetooth [Swift/iOS] - How should I approach passing the didUpdateCharacteristic value to the calling function

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, core-bluetooth

I am developing an iOS app using CoreBluetooth and utilizing the MVVM software architecture pattern.

More than one device can be connected and used simultaneously.

I have a Device model of the Peripheral that allows me to send various UART commands for writing and reading a variety of characteristics.

I am calling a read command from the model and want the response to be returned from the calling function.

I have included the command function below. As you can see it is mostly a wrapper that calls writeValue on a variety of commands.

```
func command(request : PeripheralCommand) -> Bool{
    print("Command: " + request.description())
    if let peripheral = peripheral {
        if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralState.connected {
            let data: Data = request.rawValue.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            if txCharacteristic != nil {
                print("Success")
                peripheral.writeValue(data, for: txCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
                return true
            }
            print("Error: " + ErrorPeripheralTXCharacteristicUnassigned)
            return false
        }
        print("Error: " + ErrorPeripheralDisconnected)
        return false
    }
    print("Error: " + ErrorNoPeripheral)
    return false
}
```

Generally, I will be able to handle the information by passing it by UUID to the CBDelegate but I want to be able to get the returned value in the calling function for testing and a few special cases where the responses do not directly affect the peripheral model.

Comment: The operation is asynchronous, so you can't "return" a value. Your caller is going to have to provide a closure that you can store and invoke once you have the result of the command.  Another approach is for your device model to simply publish properties that represent the physical device states. So, if there was a "weight" property, the caller might call `updateWeight`, you issue the command and when you get the response you update then`weight` property. Then caller is simply subscribed to updates to weight and doesn't need to know about command responses.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey Paul, thanks for the comment. I will attempt your second approach. Just a clarifying question. Could I have a didSet on the property within the View Model that would trigger when the property is set on the device within my BluetoothDelegate managed Device objects?

Comment: Yes, you could use a didSet.   I would use a Combine Publisher